# Restricting the area that PyAutoGui's mouse feature will work

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to make a program that randomly doodles on paint, but when I leave it alone for extended periods of time, it minimizes paint and moves every one of my files around
is there any way to keep pyautogui from moving the mouse outside of a range? Thanks in advance!

```
import pyautogui, time, random
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.click()    # click to put drawing program in focus
distance = random.randrange(200,300)
while 6 > 0:
    pyautogui.dragRel(distance, 0)   # move right
    distance = random.randrange(-50,50)
    pyautogui.dragRel(0, distance)   # move down
    distance = random.randrange(-50,50)
    pyautogui.dragRel(-distance, 0)  # move left
    distance = random.randrange(-50,50)
    pyautogui.dragRel(0, -distance)  # move up
```

I want it to stay within Top left 24,163 Bottom right 1902,996

Answer (score 0):

`pyautogui` won't do it for you, but you can track the x and y position and ensure it remains within bounds:

```
    import pyautogui, time, random

    minx = 24
    miny = 163
    maxx = 1902
    maxy = 996
    maxmove = 50
    x = (maxx-minx)/2
    y = (maxy-miny)/2
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
    pyautogui.click()    # click to put drawing program in focus


    def inx(x):
        return x <= maxx and x >= minx


    def iny(y):
        return y <= maxy and y >= miny


    def xdrag(x):
        distx = random.randrange(maxmove) - maxmove/2
        if inx(x + distx):
            x = x + distx
            pyautogui.dragRel(distx, 0)


    def ydrag(y):
        disty = random.randrange(maxmove) - maxmove/2
        if iny(y + disty):
            y = y + disty
            pyautogui.dragRel(0, disty)


    count = 0
    while count < 100: # no infinite loop
        xdrag(x)
        ydrag(y)
        count += 1
```